# Selenium Python - Text() works with Xpath but does not with CSS_Selector

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to webscrape a House listing website in Quebec and I encounter a problem.

When I use Xpath I manage to extract the phone number, but when I use CSS selectors my variable is Blank.

However I am pretty sure that I am aiming at the right spot I even used the css tool in chrome to verify.

The reason why i would need to use CSS selector is beacause the page is dynamic and not every listing is same, which means that sometimes I am not able to point out the real location using xpath like that

An example would be this URL: https://duproprio.com/fr/monteregie-rive-sud-montreal/ange-gardien-de-rouville/ferme-fermette-a-vendre/hab-707-rang-saint-charles-1008751

EXAMPLE THAT WORKS

```
        try:
            house_phone = deal_box.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/a").text.strip()
        except: house_phone = "N/D"
```

EXAMPLE THAT DOESNT WORK

```
       try:
           house_phone = deal_box.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.gtm-listing-link-contact-owner-phone').text.strip()
       except: house_phone = "N/D"
```

Thank you

Comment: You can use either CSS or XPATH to target the element you want.  The 2nd example you list that uses CSS is locating an <A> tag with a certain style (class).  Those are not guaranteed to be unique.  Use an ID if available which is unique.  Avoid using long path-based selectors.  Instead look for what is unique about the element you are targeting.  Both CSS and XPATH selectors are very flexible and have many different methods available to locate an element.

Comment: Please list a valid url

Comment: Heres a URL that works, sorry for that: https://duproprio.com/fr/monteregie-rive-sud-montreal/ange-gardien-de-rouville/ferme-fermette-a-vendre/hab-707-rang-saint-charles-1008751

Comment: @pcalkins no id's possible because it's connected to the listing itself and im scraping through a list.. also the gtm-listing-link-contact-owner-phone class seems to be unique so i dont undertsand how it could point to something else

Answer (score 0):

You can pull it from the textContent attribute

```
deal_box.get(url)
try:
    house_phone = deal_box.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.gtm-listing-link-contact-owner-phone').get_attribute('textContent').strip()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    house_phone = "N/D"
    
house_phone
```

Comment: If you have an example where the above ends up not working please share below and I will have a look. I am guessing the value you want may be in different attributes and therefore you might prefer to something like the href attribute, which could be more consistent, then remove the leading tel text.